# .htaccess - subdomain redirection when there's no slash at the end (I want subdomain.domain.eu/en -> subdomain.domain.eu/en/)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subdomain/).*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L,NC]
```

This thing shows to users content of folder `subdomain` when they navigate to `subdomain.domain.eu`. It works OK.

Recently I added support of different languages to my website.
When English speaking people enter `subdomain.domain.eu` they are redirected to `subdomain.domain.eu/en/`. And it works OK.

However, here comes the problem - when somebody navigate to `subdomain.domain.eu/en` (without the slash at the end) they're redirected to `subdomain.domain.eu/en/subdomain/` and I want them to be redirected to `subdomain.domain.eu/en/`. How to achieve that?

Comment: Add a separate redirection rule for that on top which only tests for a missing trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I didn't mess up something else but adding this (as arkascha suggested) helped:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

@edit

Yeah, it didn't work as expected, but this is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```